# What is the registry key for Windows XP to disable Internet Connection Sharing?

Tags: windows-registry, connection-sharing

What is the registry key for Windows XP to disable Internet Connection Sharing?

Answer (score 1):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\ICSharing\Settings\

Enabled (DWORD) - "1" = enable ICS, "0" = disable

Comment: Hmmm I don't appear to have the key on my machine and it's disabled for me. Any other places it could possibly be?

Comment: Are you on a domain?  If so, this may be disable through a GPO.  You may be able to find out with RSOP.MSC Hoewever, that tool could be disabled as well.  Simply click Start Then Run and enter rsop.msc in the Run box and click OK.